# Cannot deploy trained model to Google Cloud Ai-Platform with custom prediction routine: Model requires more memory than allowed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am trying to deploy a pretrained pytorch [model](https://github.com/Daniil-Osokin/lightweight-human-pose-estimation.pytorch) to AI Platform with a custom prediction routine. After following the instructions described [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/custom-prediction-routines) the deployment fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: Model requires more memory than allowed. Please try to decrease the model size and re-deploy. If you continue to have error, please contact Cloud ML.
```

The contents of the model folder are **83.89 MB** large and are below the **250 MB** limit that's described in the documentation. The only files in the folder are the checkpoint file (.pth) for the model and the tarball required for the custom prediction routine.

Command to create the model:

```
gcloud beta ai-platform versions create pose_pytorch --model pose --runtime-version 1.15 --python-version 3.5 --origin gs://rcg-models/pytorch_pose_estimation --package-uris gs://rcg-models/pytorch_pose_estimation/my_custom_code-0.1.tar.gz --prediction-class predictor.MyPredictor
```

Changing the runtime version to `1.14` leads to the same error. 
I have tried changing the --machine-type argument to `mls1-c4-m2` like Parth suggested but I still get the same error.

The `setup.py` file that generates `my_custom_code-0.1.tar.gz` looks like this:

```
setup(
    name='my_custom_code',
    version='0.1',
    scripts=['predictor.py'],
    install_requires=["opencv-python", "torch"]
)
```

Relevant code snippet from the predictor:

```
    def __init__(self, model):
        """Stores artifacts for prediction. Only initialized via `from_path`.
        """
        self._model = model
        self._client = storage.Client()

    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, model_dir):
        """Creates an instance of MyPredictor using the given path.

        This loads artifacts that have been copied from your model directory in
        Cloud Storage. MyPredictor uses them during prediction.

        Args:
            model_dir: The local directory that contains the trained Keras
                model and the pickled preprocessor instance. These are copied
                from the Cloud Storage model directory you provide when you
                deploy a version resource.

        Returns:
            An instance of `MyPredictor`.
        """

        net = PoseEstimationWithMobileNet()
        checkpoint_path = os.path.join(model_dir, "checkpoint_iter_370000.pth")
        checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint_path, map_location='cpu')
        load_state(net, checkpoint)

        return cls(net)
```

Additionally I have enabled logging for the model in AI Platform and I get the following outputs:

```
2019-12-17T09:28:06.208537Z OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k 
2019-12-17T09:28:13.474653Z WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/ml/prediction/frameworks/tf_prediction_lib.py:48: The name tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING is deprecated. Please use tf.saved_model.SERVING instead. 
2019-12-17T09:28:13.474680Z {"textPayload":"","insertId":"5df89fad00073e383ced472a","resource":{"type":"cloudml_model_version","labels":{"project_id":"rcg-shopper","region":"","version_id":"lightweight_pose_pytorch","model_id":"pose"}},"timestamp":"2019-12-17T09:28:13.474680Z","logName":"projects/rcg-shopper/logs/ml.googleapis… 
2019-12-17T09:28:13.474807Z WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/ml/prediction/frameworks/tf_prediction_lib.py:50: The name tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY is deprecated. Please use tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY instead. 
2019-12-17T09:28:13.474829Z {"textPayload":"","insertId":"5df89fad00073ecd4836d6aa","resource":{"type":"cloudml_model_version","labels":{"project_id":"rcg-shopper","region":"","version_id":"lightweight_pose_pytorch","model_id":"pose"}},"timestamp":"2019-12-17T09:28:13.474829Z","logName":"projects/rcg-shopper/logs/ml.googleapis… 
2019-12-17T09:28:13.474918Z WARNING:tensorflow: 
2019-12-17T09:28:13.474927Z The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0. 
2019-12-17T09:28:13.474934Z For more information, please see: 
2019-12-17T09:28:13.474941Z   * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md 
2019-12-17T09:28:13.474951Z   * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons 
2019-12-17T09:28:13.474958Z   * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops) 
2019-12-17T09:28:13.474964Z If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue. 
2019-12-17T09:28:13.474999Z {"textPayload":"","insertId":"5df89fad00073f778735d7c3","resource":{"type":"cloudml_model_version","labels":{"version_id":"lightweight_pose_pytorch","model_id":"pose","project_id":"rcg-shopper","region":""}},"timestamp":"2019-12-17T09:28:13.474999Z","logName":"projects/rcg-shopper/logs/ml.googleapis… 
2019-12-17T09:28:15.283483Z ERROR:root:Failed to import GA GRPC module. This is OK if the runtime version is 1.x 
2019-12-17T09:28:16.890923Z Copying gs://cml-489210249453-1560169483791188/models/pose/lightweight_pose_pytorch/15316451609316207868/user_code/my_custom_code-0.1.tar.gz... 
2019-12-17T09:28:16.891150Z / [0 files][    0.0 B/  8.4 KiB]                                                 
2019-12-17T09:28:17.007684Z / [1 files][  8.4 KiB/  8.4 KiB]                                                 
2019-12-17T09:28:17.009154Z Operation completed over 1 objects/8.4 KiB.                                       
2019-12-17T09:28:18.953923Z Processing /tmp/custom_code/my_custom_code-0.1.tar.gz 
2019-12-17T09:28:19.808897Z Collecting opencv-python 
2019-12-17T09:28:19.868579Z   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/38/60de02a4c9013b14478a3f681a62e003c7489d207160a4d7df8705a682e7/opencv_python-4.1.2.30-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (28.3MB) 
2019-12-17T09:28:21.537989Z Collecting torch 
2019-12-17T09:28:21.552871Z   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f9/34/2107f342d4493b7107a600ee16005b2870b5a0a5a165bdf5c5e7168a16a6/torch-1.3.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (734.6MB) 
2019-12-17T09:28:52.401619Z Collecting numpy>=1.14.5 
2019-12-17T09:28:52.412714Z   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/af/4fc72f9d38e43b092e91e5b8cb9956d25b2e3ff8c75aed95df5569e4734e/numpy-1.17.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (20.0MB) 
2019-12-17T09:28:53.550662Z Building wheels for collected packages: my-custom-code 
2019-12-17T09:28:53.550689Z   Building wheel for my-custom-code (setup.py): started 
2019-12-17T09:28:54.212558Z   Building wheel for my-custom-code (setup.py): finished with status 'done' 
2019-12-17T09:28:54.215365Z   Created wheel for my-custom-code: filename=my_custom_code-0.1-cp37-none-any.whl size=7791 sha256=fd9ecd472a6a24335fd24abe930a4e7d909e04bdc4cf770989143d92e7023f77 
2019-12-17T09:28:54.215482Z   Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-i7sb0bmb/wheels/0d/6e/ba/bbee16521304fc5b017fa014665b9cae28da7943275a3e4b89 
2019-12-17T09:28:54.222017Z Successfully built my-custom-code 
2019-12-17T09:28:54.650218Z Installing collected packages: numpy, opencv-python, torch, my-custom-code
```

Comment: Can you try and run it with a) --machine-type=mls-c4-m2 b) --runtime-version 1.14 c) try a) and b) together ?

Comment: I updated my question to include your suggestions.

Comment: sorry for the typo, the machine-type should be mls1-c4-m2 instead.

Comment: Tried it with all the cases. Still get the same memory error.

Comment: when you test your model local prediction works fine? I will see Pytorch model details and see If I can reproduce.

Comment: If you mean gcloud ai-platform local predict then no because as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/deploying-models#test_your_model_with_local_predictions) local predictions do not work with custom prediction routines. The model however works fine when I manually run it on my computer.

Comment: I meant when you use the Python class and load it locally and then send predictions.  Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56262008/260826

Comment: Yeah it works that way. I've already deployed some models previously to Ai Platform and didn't have any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem and we understand this is a pain point. Please do the following:

1. `torchvision` has `torch` as dependency and by default, it pulls `torch` from pypi.

When deploying the model, even if you point to use custom ai-platform `torchvision` packages it will do it, since `torchvision` when is built by PyTorch team, it is configured to use `torch` as dependency. This `torch` dependency from pypi, gives a 720mb file because it includes the GPU units

2. To solve #1, you need to [build](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/85b8fbfd31e9324e64e24ca25410284ef238bcb3/README.rst) `torchvision` from source and tell `torchvision` where you want to get `torch` from, you need to set it to go to the `torch` website as the package is smaller. Rebuild the `torchvision` binary using Python [PEP-0440 direct references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references) feature. In `torchvision` [setup.py](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/v0.5.0/setup.py#L65) we have:

```
pytorch_dep = 'torch'
if os.getenv('PYTORCH_VERSION'):
    pytorch_dep += "==" + os.getenv('PYTORCH_VERSION')
```

Update `setup.py` in `torchvision` to use direct references feature:

```
requirements = [
     #'numpy',
     #'six',
     #pytorch_dep,
     'torch @ https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.4.0%2Bcpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl'
]
```

*** I already did this for you***,  so I build 3 wheel files you can use:

```
gs://dpe-sandbox/torchvision-0.4.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl (torch 1.2.0, vision 0.4.0)
gs://dpe-sandbox/torchvision-0.4.2-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl (torch 1.2.0, vision 0.4.2)
gs://dpe-sandbox/torchvision-0.5.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl (torch 1.4.0  vision 0.5.0)
```

These `torchvision` packages will get `torch` from the torch site instead of pypi: (Example: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.4.0%2Bcpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl)

3. Update your model `setup.py` when deploying the model to AI Platform so it does not include `torch` nor `torchvision`.
4. Redeploy the model as follows:

```
PYTORCH_VISION_PACKAGE=gs://dpe-sandbox/torchvision-0.5.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl

gcloud beta ai-platform versions create {MODEL_VERSION} --model={MODEL_NAME} \
            --origin=gs://{BUCKET}/{GCS_MODEL_DIR} \
            --python-version=3.7 \
            --runtime-version={RUNTIME_VERSION} \
            --machine-type=mls1-c4-m4 \
            --package-uris=gs://{BUCKET}/{GCS_PACKAGE_URI},{PYTORCH_VISION_PACKAGE}\
            --prediction-class={MODEL_CLASS}
```

You can change the `PYTORCH_VISION_PACKAGE` to any of the options I mentioned in #2

Comment: I'm also using a larger machine: mls1-c4-m4. In few weeks Custom Prediction will support the other Google Compute engine instance we support.

Answer (score 2):

I could succeed by tweaking `setup.py`. Basically `install_requires` try to fetch PyPI hosted `torch` package which is a huge GPU built wheel and that is exceeding the deployment quota. The following `setup.py` injects install commands that fetches CPU built torch from the official pytorch index.

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.install import install as _install

INSTALL_REQUIRES = ['pillow']

CUSTOM_INSTALL_COMMANDS = [
    # Install torch here.
    [
        'python-default', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--target=/tmp/custom_lib',
        '-b', '/tmp/pip_builds', 'torch==1.4.0+cpu', 'torchvision==0.5.0+cpu',
        '-f', 'https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html'
    ],
]

class Install(_install):
    def run(self):
        import sys
        if sys.platform == 'linux':
            import subprocess
            import logging
            for command in CUSTOM_INSTALL_COMMANDS:
                logging.info('Custom command: ' + ' '.join(command))
                result = subprocess.run(
                    command, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE
                )
                logging.info(result.stdout.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
        _install.run(self)

setup(
    name='predictor',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=INSTALL_REQUIRES,
    cmdclass={'install': Install},
)
```

Comment: I have the same problem but when I changed my setup.py according to yours I get this:      ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error:  "There was a problem processing the user code: predictor.MyPredictor cannot be found. Please make sure (1) prediction_class is the fully qualified function name

Answer (score 2):

After hours of good old trial errors, I came to the same conclusion as @kyamagu, "`install_requires` try to fetch PyPI hosted torch package which is a huge GPU built wheel and that is exceeding the deployment quota."

However, his solution did not work for me. So after many more hours of trial errors (thanks to lacking documentation and wrong ones) I came up with this solution:

We need to get the cpu-built wheels of the Pytorch which is around 100 MBs rather than the 700 MBs GPU-builts that are the default PyPI hosted. you can find them here: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html

Next, we need to place them in our gs storage and then give the path as part of the --package-uris like this:

```
gcloud beta ai-platform versions create v17 \
    --model=newest \
    --origin=gs://bucket \
    --runtime-version=1.15 \
    --python-version=3.7 \
    --package-uris=gs://bucket/predictor-0.1.tar.gz,gs://bucket/torch-1.3.0+cpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl \
    --prediction-class=predictor.MyPredictor \
    --machine-type=mls1-c4-m4
```

Also, watch out for the order of the `package-uris`, the `predictor` package should be first and there should not be any space after commas.

Hope this helps. cheers!